# Are upstart jobs guaranteed to be given time to run?

Tags: linux, bash, shutdown, ubuntu-server, upstart

I am writing an upstart job that runs a shell script at startup and shutdown which synchronizes some files with a remote machine using rsync.  The script can sometimes take a long time to complete if a lot of files have changed.  As far as I can tell, the shutdown process includes a part where it kills all jobs that are taking too long to terminate.  Is there any chance that this could kill the script (which is run in the `pre-stop` part of the process, or is the script guaranteed to be allowed to run until it terminates before the computer continues with shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-stop), `pre-stop` is indeed the place to do this.